# Summation Program

Tags: python, function, integer, sum

I am trying to create a simple function that will take the summation numbers given an integer from 0. For example, If the user inputs the integer 3, the results would be 6, since 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 6.

What is the best/most efficient way to do this?

Eventually I want to create a loop that will do this for a list, where the user inputs the list [4, 5, 6] and the function would return [10, 15, 16].

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems you want to use [factorial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) function.

Answer (score 2):

There exists a closed form solution which has constant time (rather than linear time), which will be vastly faster than any iterative solution.  The `//` divide operator forces an integer result (in case you're using Python 3).

```
def mysum(n):
    return n*(n+1)//2
```

If you want to apply this to a list, you can use `map`:

```
def mysum2(li):
    return map(mysum, li)
```

Or you can do it directly, without using `mysum` (this will be fastest):

```
def mysum2(li):
    return [n*(n+1)//2 for n in li]
```

The closed-form solutions will work on much larger values than the iterative solutions.  For example:

```
>>> mysum2([4, 5, 6, 10000000000000])
[10, 15, 21, 50000000000005000000000000]
>>>
```

The solutions that use `sum` will never return a result for a case like this.

Answer (score 1):

For a single input, you can use

```
def summer(n):
     # Create a list of numbers from 0 to n.
     # The range function is an end-exclusive range
     return sum(range(n+1))
```

For multiple inputs, use the `map` function

```
def multisummer(ns):
    return map(summer, ns)
```

Comment: This isn't even close to being the "best/most efficient way to do this".

Answer (score 1):

```
X = [4,6,7]
X = [x*(x+1)/2 for x in X]
```

Answer (score 1):

time complexity: `O(n)`

```
def get_sum(a):
   return [n * (n + 1) / 2 for n in a]


if __name__ == '__main__':
   print get_sum([4, 5, 6])
```

result: [10, 15, 21]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Answer (score 0):

The summation function would be useful here.

```
def findsum(x):
    # The 0 is optional, but it makes it clear that you are starting from 0.
    return sum(range(0, x + 1))
```

So for example:

```
>>> findsum(6)
21
```

Comment: This isn't even close to being the "best/most efficient way to do this".

Comment: That wasn't the question though.  Tell me, what result does your function give you for `findsum(10000000000)`?